# c# grab image from video card - Canopus ADVC-55

Tags: c#, capture, video-capture

Any advice on how I might grab an image using C# from this device (Canopus ADVC-55)

I tried emailing the manufacture but they where not interested as they sell it with their own software products.

Cheers,
jason

[Canopus-ADVC-55](http://www.scan.co.uk/Products/Canopus-ADVC-55-Advanced-Digital-Video-Converter-Best-Seller)

Comment: Looks like it's a simple DV-capturing device. You should look into DirectShow and stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it myself, but maybe DirectShow would work?